# Firebase Exception "Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app crashes on button click and log shows the Firebase Exception- "Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations"

Here is the class..

```
public class tt extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{ Member member = new Member();
    DatabaseReference  reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
    doit ok = new doit();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        member.go();

        ok.setAd_id(member.ad_id);
        ok.setPrice(member.price);
        ok.setUsername(member.username);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {        reff.push().setValue(ok);



            }
        });
        thread.run();
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the log....

```
05-12 18:24:44.824 23423-24354/com.example.btc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
    Process: com.example.btc, PID: 23423
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: isChangingConfigurations
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:477)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:329)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:282)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:159)
        at com.example.btc.tt$1.run(tt.java:24)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
        at com.example.btc.tt.doInBackground(tt.java:30)
        at com.example.btc.tt.doInBackground(tt.java:11)
```

Comment: Please show your pojo. Did you create pojo in separate file ?

Comment: @Ashish What do you mean by pojo

Comment: Please read this quora [answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-POJO-in-Java). Might help you to understand what i am asking for you

Comment: @Ashish Thanks but solved it by hash map

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using hash map....

```
public class tt extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{ Member member = new Member();
    DatabaseReference  reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
    doit ok = new doit();
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        member.go();

        ok.setAd_id(member.ad_id);
        ok.setPrice(member.price);
        ok.setUsername(member.username);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                HashMap<String,String>
                        Student = new HashMap<>();
                Student.put("Ad_id",ok.Ad_id);
                Student.put("Price",ok.Price);
                Student.put("Username",ok.Username);
                reff.push().setValue(Student);



            }
        });
        thread.run();
        return null;
    }


}
```